# Docusaurus. Sidebar is unique per page, bug or feature?

Tags: docusaurus

In docusaurus, if we declare **the same doc** in 2 sidebars, the sidebar is not respected and the doc always will show the last sidebar declaration, not matter from where the doc is accessed.

```
  sidebar1: [
    {
        type: 'doc',
        id: 'folder/intro',
        label: 'Getting started',
    }, {
    ...

  sidebar2: [
    {
        type: 'doc',
        id: 'folder/intro',
        label: 'Getting started',
    }, {
    ...
```

I would expect that, when opening the page, the sidebar declaration is maintained from the  sidebar that the document is opened.

Is this a bug?